# Why does the compiler complain "while expected" when I try to add more code?

Tags: java

Write a program with a word containing @ character as an input. If the word doesn't contain @, it should prompt the user for a word with @. Once a word with @ is read, it should output the word then terminate.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public class find {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(" Please enter a word with @ ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String bad = "@";

        String word = scan.next();
        do
            if (!word.contains(bad))
                System.out.println(" Please try again ");
            else
                System.out.println(" " + word);
        while (!word.contains(bad));
    }
}
```

I can get it to terminate after a word containing "@" is given as input, but if I try to add a Scanner to the line after "please try again", it says `while expected`.

Comment: It is always better do/while, if/else,for etc., code surrounded with open/close braces.

Comment: What is your question? Does your code compile? If not, what is the *exact* error message. Copy and paste it here so we can help you.

Comment: You mean brackets.  But truth be told this would execute as expected since there isn't multiple statements in the block.

Comment: @Makoto: I think issue is with do/while.

Comment: @Nambari post it as the answer, since the OP wants to read a new word on each loop, brackets are required, because this sums in 2 statements.

Comment: @Makoto: *this* would execute as expected, yes.  However it would be difficult to add another statement to such a loop, which is exactly the problem the OP is describing.

Comment: @MouseEvent: Added as answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware that this would work but there are serious issues with it otherwise.  Merely pointing it out.

Comment: ok i added the brackets and now when i try to add another scanner in the if statement after " Please try again " it error when compiling says "else" without " if "

Comment: Now again, add brackets to the if statement....

Answer (score 6):

I think issue is you are missing surrounding braces for do/while:

```
       do
          if (!word.contains( bad ))
            System.out.println( " Please try again " );

            else 
            System.out.println( " " + word);

        while ( !word.contains( bad ));
```

should be:

```
do
{
            if (!word.contains( bad ))
            System.out.println( " Please try again " );

            else 
            System.out.println( " " + word);
}while ( !word.contains( bad ));
```

Some people may not like this, but my suggestion is always use open/close braces. In this case, for the code if/else also. It avoids lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is where your problem lies:

```
       do
            if (!word.contains(bad))
                System.out.println(" Please try again ");
            else
                System.out.println(" " + word);
        while (!word.contains(bad));
```

You need to put braces from where the loop starts until it ends. |So this thing should like:

```
do {
    if (!word.contains(bad))
        System.out.println(" Please try again ");
    else
        System.out.println(" " + word);
} while(!word.contains(bad));
```

For Better Practice You should Check `do...while` loops [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Comment: This answer would be better if it described with words exactly *what* changed in the new code, so readers don't have to play spot-the-difference, and then explained *why* the difference is important.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Yeah... I'll keep that in mind next time. Thanks :)

Comment: Why not fix the answer now?  There's still time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. Your code is not using the braces properly
2. you are not attempting to read the new word if right word is not entered.

Also I prefer `while` loop better in the case as opposed to `do-while` loop as below.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );
    String required= "@";
    System.out.println( " Please enter a word with @ " );
    String word = scan.next() ;

    //check if the right word(containing @) is entered, 
    //if not then loop until it is enteres
    while((!word.contains(required)){
        System.out.println( " Please try again " );
        //read the new word as input from the user
        word = scan.next() ;
    }
    //right word is entered, display it
    System.out.println(word);
```

Also please note that when you use `scan.next()`, it reads each word separately if entered in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is it is not re-reading the word in your loop.
Modify your loop like this (minimum change to your code).

```
do {
        word = scan.next();
        if (!word.contains(bad))
            System.out.println(" Please try again ");

        else
            System.out.println(" " + word);
    }
    while (!word.contains(bad));
```

And yes as others have pointed out try to use braces especially with nested constructs.