# Java Loop Until add elements

Tags: java, loops

I am creating a restaurant system and im trying to add tables when i create my restaurant. I can add 1 table using an if statement but im trying to get it to add multiple tables until addTbl does not equal Y. I've tried a variation of different kinds of loops but none of them work and i keep getting an error.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

addRestaurant method:

```
public static List<Restaurant> addRestaurants(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {

    int newRestaurantId = Restaurant.getnumberOfRestaurants() + 1;
    String restaurantName= readString("Enter New Restaurant Name");
    String restaurantLocation= readString("Enter New Restaurant Locaition");

    char addTbl = readString("Add Table?: (Y/N)").toUpperCase().charAt(0);


    if (addTbl == 'Y') {

    int newTableId = Table.getNumberOfTables() +1;
    int seats = readInt("Enter Table Seats", 30, 1);
    Table rt = new Table(newRestaurantId, restaurantName, restaurantLocation, newTableId, seats);
     restaurants.add(rt);

    }
     else{

    Restaurant r = new Restaurant(newRestaurantId, restaurantName, restaurantLocation);
    restaurants.add(r);   
             }
    return restaurants;

}
```

If you require more code then please just ask.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error that you keep getting?

Comment: @BlakePnot in this code this is reverted back to when it originally worked.

Comment: Not sure how this is working in the first place... `restaurants` is a `List<Restaurant>` but you are trying to add a `Table` to it. That shouldn't work...

Comment: @BlakeP It works. Table is a separate class from restaurant. Table extends restaurant.

Comment: Gotcha. That wasn't very intuitive, as Table extending Restaurant seems odd - one would expect the Restaurant to just have a list of tables. But we aren't trying to code review, just fix bugs.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are wanting to do is use something like a do-while loop.

```
do {
    char addTbl = readString("Add Table?: (Y/N)").toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    if (addTbl == 'Y') {
        int newTableId = Table.getNumberOfTables() +1;
        int seats = readInt("Enter Table Seats", 30, 1);
        Table rt = new Table(newRestaurantId, restaurantName, restaurantLocation, newTableId, seats);
        restaurants.add(rt);
    }else{
        Restaurant r = new Restaurant(newRestaurantId, restaurantName, restaurantLocation);
        restaurants.add(r);   
    }
}while(addTble != 'N');
```

So the loop will continue until `N` is the input. Or change it to fit what you are needing (like using `Q` for quit).

Comment: that is correct but i'm now getting an error "while expected" and i cannot close the method?

Comment: You will have to post the code and the stack trace. Potentially related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813813/why-does-the-compiler-complain-while-expected-when-i-try-to-add-more-code